# R deploy scripts that depend on some packages in new machines

Tags: r, install.packages

I have a bundle of R scripts that are running on my local machine so far.

The different scripts need a set of packages.

I need to deploy scripts on other machines in the lab.

What is the optimal way to re-use the packages that I have on my local machine, to the other machines.

Should I keep the list that I have on local and re-install it on any remaining machine?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: The optimal way is to build a package from your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/), or think of using [MRAN](https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine) instead of CRAN.